# Loading backbone template by using the router string

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am creating backbone view, which it's contents is dynamically loaded by parameter string of router. So I create a view with a main template and multiple sub templates.

Here is my view :

```
define(["jquery" ,
 "underscore" ,
 "backbone" ,
 "text!templates/Content/confirmMessageTemplate.html",
 "text!templates/Content/registerMessage.html",
 "text!templates/Content/signInMessage.html"
],function($ , _ ,Backbone,ConfirmMessageTem,RegisterMessage,SignInMessage){
 var teView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.options = options || {};
    },
    render: function(){
        var message = _.template(ConfirmMessageTem);
        var subtem = _.template(RegisterMessage); 
        this.$el.html(message({msgheader:this.options.msgheader, body:subtem()}));
    }
 });
 return teView;
});
```

`body:subtem()` is throwing sub template to the main template.

`this.options.title[0]` gets string value (RegisterMessage, SignInMessage,.....) So what I want is to load my sub template dynamically like :

```
var subtem = _.template(this.options.title[0]);
```

But I couldn't archive it due to `this.options.title[0]` return string.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: some thing like this ? ` render: function() { tmpPath = this.options.title[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.options.title[0].slice(1);    require(tmpPath, function(path) {   var tmp = _.template(path); this.$el.html(...)  })  } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only a few dynamically selectable templates, something like this could be done:

```
define(["jquery" ,
    "underscore" ,
    "backbone" ,
    "text!templates/Content/confirmMessageTemplate.html",
    "text!templates/Content/registerMessage.html",
    "text!templates/Content/signInMessage.html"
],function($, _, Backbone, ConfirmMessageTem, RegisterMessage, SignInMessage){

    var teView = Backbone.View.extend({

        // make a hash of templates and attach that hash to teView, where key of 
        // the hash would be the router string that is returned in 
        // this.options.title[0] in your render method
        templatesHash: {

            "RegisterMessage": RegisterMessage,
            "SignInMessage": SignInMessage

        },

        initialize: function(options) {
            this.options = options || {};
        },

        render: function(){
            var message = _.template(ConfirmMessageTem);

            // and here subtem can be initialized as below -
            // by reading the template from the templatesHash
            // var subtem = _.template(RegisterMessage); 
            var subtem = _.template( this.templatesHash[ this.options.title[0] ] );

            this.$el.html(message({msgheader:this.options.msgheader, body:subtem()}));
        }

    });

    return teView;
});
```

Comment: `this.templatesHash[ this.options.title[0] ` is undefined when I did `console.log` in the browser.

Comment: Could you please check, what does it print for `this.templatesHash` in console ? And also, `this.options.title[0]`.

Comment: Cool, then the only reason for `this.templatesHash[ this.options.title[0] ]` to be undefined would be `this.options.title[0]` isn't in the keys of that object, may be you'll have to change that logic according to your needs.

Comment: Ah... I got it, I have changed `title` to `header`, that's why it is undefined. Now, it's fixed. But I still have a problem, while there is no template for some of router string, then what should I do.

Comment: If for a router string there is no template, then what value would you want the `subtem` variable to contain ?

Comment: Then, I want `this.$el.html(message({msgheader:this.options.msgheader, body:''}));` , Is it possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73052/discussion-between-cyclone-and-nothing).